# Mac GridView equivalent

Tags: database, macos, grid

I'm new to the Mac platform. What is the equivalent to Windows or DevExpress GridView on the Mac that can consume and update a datasource? If there is none can you explain what is the mac way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with GridView, but it sounds like you want an [`NSTableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

The Cocoa way of doing this is by using a table view with a correctly set up delegate and controller that communicates with the external datasource.

Before trying to find Windows equivalents in Cocoa - have a read through the docs that mipaldi pointed you at. You'll find it easier to pick up Mac OS X programming, especially the [MVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1) pattern that is used throughout, if you don't keep relating to the way things are done on Windows.

Also - if you use Core Data as a data store, you can drop your model onto a window in the Interface Builder view and it will set up a basic UI for you.